# Drag and drop in datatables

Tags: laravel

Hope you are doing well. Kindly help me out here.  I am using Yajra data tables in laravel 5.3. I need to implement UI sorting ( drag and drop ), like when showing some records in datatable, i want to change the order of records and then save it back to data base through drag and drop. If there is any package or some useful links, kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/ - Take a look at the examples

Comment: I followed this example and when i drag a row and drop it it works but for milli seconds, as it again restores the data table and goes again to previous state

Comment: Then search how to fix that instead of requesting an entirely different and most likely unsupported method. I bet that you probably still have table ordering on and that it resets the table order when you try to move one.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Yajra, but it looks like it makes Jquery datatables (https://datatables.net/) that seem quite sortable already. 
For the drag and drop you might want to have a look at jquery sortable (https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/)

Hope that helps you find the way!

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below link,

http://web1.cs-computing.com/apps/demo/bootstrap/bootstrap_demo.nsf/dnd.xsp

I had tried this and it is working with me. Multiple options are there with drag, drop and sort.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response.